# Checking the location every 10 minutes in the background

Tags: android, gps, location

My requirement is to check the location of the device every 10 minutes using a background service. So the basic gist of what should happen every 10 minutes is this -

- Start the service.
- Wait a minute (maximum) for the listener to get a location, once the location is taken, remove the listener and then stop the service.
- If the listener doesn't respond, use getLastKnownLocation(), remove the listener and then stop the service.
- If the GPS is off, it reports to the app (this step is working fine)

What I have tried doing till now -

- Made a service which is triggered every 10 minutes using an AlarmManager
- Added a Location Listener inside this service.
- onLocationChanged() from the LocationListener has the method - stopSelf() included, so that the service ends after receiving a location. However, this method is called a numerous times. I checked that while debugging. Is this because there are many instances of onLocationChanged() called ?

I don't need an entire code as the answer, I would rather appreciate a strategy I should adopt which will fulfil my requirements without hurting the battery much. As with my approach, unless and until the location is found, the GPS remains ON draining the battery constantly.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of alarm manager which is scheduling each 10 min, use the [FusedLocationAPI](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/location/index.html) and [location request](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest) in order to get accurate location.

```
            LocationRequest mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
            mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);//Change to PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY for more accurate.
            mLocationRequest.setInterval(600000); // Update location every 10 minute
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                    mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
```

Call this method whenever you need the location

```
/**
 * Get the Location Detail from Fused Location API.
 * @param mContext
 * @return
 */
private Location getLocationDetails(Context mContext) {
    Location location = null;
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.d(TAG,"Location Permission Denied");
            return null;
        }else {
            location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        }
    }
    return location;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try with this

```
// The minimum distance to change updates in meters
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters

// The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 10; // 10 minute
```

for more info example try with this

[Try with this link click here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

> onLocationChanged() from the LocationListener has the method - stopSelf() included, so that the service ends after receiving a location. However, this method is called a numerous times. I checked that while debugging. Is this because there are many instances of onLocationChanged() called ?

Basically, when you receive the first location, also stopping the service via stopSelf() thats okay too.

But how the onLocationChanged method being called numerous time ?

Dont you remove location updates when the service shutting down ?